# Web Service Connection Refused in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, json, web-services

I'm trying to build a simple Web Service application in ASP.NET C# and make a call from another project written in PHP. The problem when I make an AJAX call I get this error:

> POST http://localhost:49566/WebApplication2/ReviewService.asmx/getReviewById net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have added "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in my Web.config:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="localDatabase" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=mydb;Uid=root;Pwd=gameover;" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

This is my $.ajax call from PHP:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.ajax( {
    method:'post',
    data: {user_id: 1},
    url:'http://localhost:49566/WebApplication2/ReviewService.asmx/getReviewById',
    success:function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
    })
});
```

I really don't know what is the problem here. Thanks for your help

Comment: actually the ajax call is javascript (jQuery) and not php. maybe you should tag it properly for best chances on help

Comment: Maybe I explained a bit wrong - That project uses PHP and ofcourse ajax call is made with jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems when running in Visual Studio debugger (VS2013). In debugger everything worked great (when running inside VS), but when I stopped debugger, site was no longer available.
As it turned out, it was setting "Edit and continue" which was enabled on ASP.NET project, which is enabled by default. Turning this setting off made my site (or webservice) available on localhost even when I stopped debugger. I also got ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to browse to a site, before turning this setting off. That means you are not able to correct code while debugging, but that was ok for me.

Comment: I'm running IIS and Wamp server at the same time - and I can browse to both local project - the problem is I can not make CORS request returning net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Maybe you can try adding additional headers and see if it works:  
  "Access-Control-Request-Method", "\*"
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "\*"